# Consolidating two identities involving $\csc(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I know that $$ \csc(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(x + n \pi)}$$ and $$\csc^2(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x + n \pi)^2}.$$ Starting with the first identity, if I square it then we get $$\csc^2(x)  = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x + n \pi)^2} + 2 \sum_{-\infty < m < n < \infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{(x + m\pi)(x + n\pi)}.$$ I am trying to show that $$\sum_{-\infty < m < n < \infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{(x + m\pi)(x + n\pi)} = 0.$$ Edit: Following @Conrad's hints I got the following. First, the sum can be written as $$\sum_{-\infty < m < n < \infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{\pi(n-m)}\left[\frac{1}{x + m\pi} - \frac{1}{x + n\pi}\right].$$ Then for a fixed $m$, we have the following two terms in this sum $$\frac{(-1)^{m-k + m}}{\pi k}\left[\frac{1}{x + (m-k)\pi} - \frac{1}{x + m\pi}\right] + \frac{(-1)^{m+m+k}}{\pi k}\left[\frac{1}{x + m\pi} - \frac{1}{x + (m+k)\pi}\right]$$ which simplifies to $$\frac{(-1)^k}{\pi k}\left[\frac{1}{x + (m-k)\pi} - \frac{1}{x + (m+k)\pi}\right] = \frac{2(-1)^k}{(x + m\pi)^2 - (k\pi)^2}.$$ So the sum simplifies to $$\sum_{m = -\infty}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2(-1)^k}{(x + m\pi)^2 - (k\pi)^2}.$$

But I am unsure of how to proceed from here...

Comment: write $\frac{1}{(x + m\pi)(x + n\pi)}=(\frac{1}{x + m\pi}-\frac{1}{x + n\pi})/(\pi(n-m))$ and collect all the terms for a fixed $m$ and show they cancel out in pairs

Comment: @Conrad I got them to cancel out in pairs, but then was left with $\lim_{N \to -\infty} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{x + (N +k)\pi} \sum_{\ell = k + 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^\ell}{\ell}$ but I am not sure how to show this sum is $0$.

Comment: You didn't count correctly as for fixed $m$ each term appears twice and with opposite signs for the ones with same distance to $m$

Comment: Sorry by this do you mean: Fix and $m$ and consider $m-k,m$ and $m,m+k$?

Comment: yes - and note that the factor (apart from signs and $\pi$) is $1/k$ for both so you need to show that the signs behave well so they cancel and of course that the summation is valid since now those series are only conditionally convergent

Comment: @Conrad Is this the simplification you were leading towards? I'm not sure how to proceed from here

Comment: No; first write the sum of products as once for each pair $(n,m), n \ne m$ rather than order them; fix $m$ and just consider the terms $\frac{1}{x + m\pi}$; each such appears twice for each $n \ne m$ (from the term $(n,m)$ and the term $(m,n)$ and the coefficient each time is $\pm 1/(\pi |n-m|)$ - from $(n,m)$ we get $(-1)^{m+n+1}/\pi(n-m)$ and from $(m,n)$ we get $(-1)^{m+n}/\pi(m-n)$ so they have same sign;  if $n_1=m+k, n_2=m+k, k >0$ one gets same sign for $m+n_1$ vs $m+n_2$ but the modulus changes sign for $n_1$ vs $n_2$ so the terms (with each appearing twice) cancel out